# Prevent development.log backlog from delaying server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ever notice this Rails dev server behavior?

1. Start `rails server`
2. Run some commands in "rails console" or a script, appending content to `development.log`
3. Make a request to the dev server you started in step #1
4. The server hangs, because it's waiting for the server process to write out to the terminal all the new text from step #2

Is there a way to stop that? It's especially annoying with the combination of an infrequently-accessed server and a frequently-polling background process.

I understand that the theoretical solution is to make the Rails dev server write to its log asynchronously, but I'm hoping someone's already written something so I don't have to hack it up myself.